# How to use df.apply() by passing selected columns of a dataframe to another function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. Two of the columns in the dataframe are table_name and column_name. I need to check whether the column_name is available in the table_name in an SQL Server database.

Now, I have a function check_column_existence() for this, which seems to work fine, if I use the traditional method of reading the csv file and calling the function:

```
def check_column_existence(dbHost, dbPort, dbName, dbUser, dbPassword, table_name, column_name):
    sqlQuery="""select count(*) from 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
where table_name='{}' and column_name='{}';""".format(table_name, column_name)
    conn = pymssql.connect(host=dbHost, port=dbPort, user=dbUser, password=dbPassword, database=dbName)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = sqlQuery.encode('utf-8')
    cursor.execute(sql)
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == 1:
            result = True
        else:
            result = False
    print(result)
    return result

def populate_db_attribute_existence(dbHost, dbPort, dbName, dbUser, dbPassword, input_csv_file_path):
    input_csv_file_path = os.path.abspath(input_csv_file_path)
    input_csv_folder_path = os.path.dirname(input_csv_file_path)
    input_csv_file_name = os.path.basename(input_csv_file_path)
    temp1_output_file_path = "{}/temp1_{}".format(input_csv_folder_path, input_csv_file_name)
    temp2_output_file_path = "{}/temp2_{}".format(input_csv_folder_path, input_csv_file_name)

    df = pd.read_csv(input_csv_file_path)
    df['DB_Entity'] = df['DB_Entity'].str.replace(' ', '')
    df['DB_Attributes'] = df['DB_Attributes'].str.replace(' ', '')
    df2 = df[['API_Attributes', 'DB_Entity', 'DB_Attributes']]
    df2.to_csv(temp1_output_file_path, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

    with open(temp1_output_file_path,'r') as ftemp1, open(temp2_output_file_path,'w') as ftemp2:
        i = 1
        for row in ftemp1:
            if i > 1:
                row = row.strip()
                list_columns = row.split(',')
                api_attr_name = list_columns[0]
                db_entity_name = list_columns[1]
                c_name = list_columns[2]
                t_name = 'dbo.{}'.format(db_entity_name)
                result = check_column_existence(dbHost, dbPort, dbName, dbUser, dbPassword, t_name, c_name)
                ftemp2.write(','.join([api_attr_name, db_entity_name, c_name, str(result)])+'\n')
            i += 1



    del(df2)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(temp2_output_file_path, names=['API_Attributes', 'DB_Entity', 'DB_Attributes', 'DB_Attr_Exist'])
    merge_key = ['API_Attributes', 'DB_Attributes']
    merged_df = pd.merge(df, df2, on=merge_key, how='outer')
    merged_df.to_csv(input_csv_file_path, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    os.remove(temp1_output_file_path)
    os.remove(temp2_output_file_path)
    print("Completed DB Attributes existence check: {}".format(input_csv_file_path))
```

Updated this question with my current approach. Please recommend if there are faster ways to achieve the same. How should I use df.apply() or a lambda function in this context, if possible?

Appreciate your help or recommendation in advance.

Comment: [Are you sure you want to be using `apply`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

Comment: @coldspeed Not necessarily. My current solution is now updated along with my question, I was just curious if there is a better, more efficient way to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

There are different possible improvements in your code.

First (which is your question), you use temporary csv files only to browse a dataframe row wise. `apply` is bad as explained by @coldspeed, but using the disk is even worse.

As you already have a Python function that you want to apply row wise to an existing dataframe to add a new column, it is an acceptable use case for `apply`. A direct access to the underlying numpy arrays is certainly faster, but pandas has been created to have a *convenient* framework and convenience comes at a cost. So here you could add a new column to your dataframe with:

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_csv_file_path)
df['DB_Entity'] = df['DB_Entity'].str.replace(' ', '')
df['DB_Attributes'] = df['DB_Attributes'].str.replace(' ', '')
df['DB_Attr_Exist'] = df.apply(lambda x: check_column_existence(
                          dbHost, dbPort, dbName, dbUser, dbPassword,
                          'dbo'+x['DB_Entity'], x['DB_Attributes'])
```

Next in the `check_column_existence` function, you create a new database connection for every line. That is a rather expensive operation, and you really should open it once before processing the file and close it only at the end.

Comment: Thank you for spending time to review my question and for providing your feedback. I will definitely incorporate both your suggestions